# Deploy Rails 4 app to Windows Server 2012

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ruby-on-rails-4, windows-server-2012-r2

So I have been tasked with deploying a RoR4 app to a windows server 2012 R2 environment. This is an enterprise app that is being installed into a local network. Unfortunately (though I begged), other OS's are not an option.

I honestly don't know where to start, I have only every deployed to linux using unicorn, apache/nginx. So that is where I planned on starting.

Anyone have any good documentation or suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: You're looking at deploying on WIndows IIS. Here's a possible duplicate question that seems to have solid suggestions:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305043/ruby-on-rails-on-iis

Comment: IIS sounds like it may be the best fit, perhaps with puma. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Good luck with this!