# is there an easy way to run rails app on iis?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iis

i need to deploy my rails app on iis, but the server is fully closed and I literally can't read anything from outside. I've checked that is possible with puma and other stuff like docker or httpplatformhandler, but that doesn't work.

Is there an "easy way" to deploy this?

Thanks

Comment: Can [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3305043) help you? I think you face the same scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to run rails on IIS is to install [helicon zoo](http://www.helicontech.com/zoo/).